# simple sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 tables as follows.

```
salesman(sid,sname)
location(lid,lname)
sales_loc(sid,lid)
```

Now i want to print the sid and sname of saleman who has visited all locations.
I want a SQL query and I don't want a PL/SQL code.

Comment: I was about to guess homework. But homework rarely involves software like Oracle ...

Comment: Well, there is an Express version now ;)

Comment: Maybe something went "whoosh" over my head, but I'm having a hard time understanding what you're asking. How are these two tables linked in any way?

Comment: Greg: `sales_loc` has a foreign key on both `salesman` and `location`, thereby linking the two tables :-)

Comment: okay -- sorry for interrupting... i need to go to bed

Answer (score 7):

```
select sid, sname from salesman
where not exists 
        (select 1 from location
          where not exists
                  (select 1 from sales_loc
                    where sid=saleman.sid 
                     and lid = location.lid));
```

Comment: Oookay, that's an interesting one. Never really thought about that you could negate the statement; nice.

Comment: Yeah, I'm still trying to wrap my head around it :)

Comment: Lewisham: I've been everywhere when there is no location where i haven't been.

Answer (score 4):

Another approach:

```
select sid, sname from salesman
where
  (select count(*) from location) =
  (select count(*) from sales_loc where sales_loc.sid = salesman.sid)
```

**Edit:**
In case `sales_loc(sid,lid)` pair isn't a key, the below query is more appropriate,
as ammoQ suggested:

```
select sid, sname from salesman
where
  (select count(*) from location) =
  (select count(distinct lid) from sales_loc where sales_loc.sid = salesman.sid)
```

Comment: +1, although it makes some assumptions; I'd make the second subquery a "select count(distinct lid) ..." so it still works when there is more than one entry in sales_loc for a salesman and a location

Comment: @ammoQ, you are right. I made that assumption. I'll edit my answer to include your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Get all salesman recs where number of locations visited equals number of locations.

```
select sm.* from salesman as sm
where (select count(sl.*) from sales_loc as sl where sl.sid = sm.sid)
 = (select count(l.*) from location as l);
```

Answer (score 0):

One more for the pot!

Given these salesmen and their territories ...

```
SQL> select s.sname, l.lname
  2  from   salesman s
  3         , location l
  4         , sales_loc sl
  5  where  sl.sid = s.sid
  6  and sl.lid = l.lid
  7  order by s.sid, l.lid
  8  /

SNAME      LNAME
---------- ----------
FOX        TRAIN
FOX        BOAT
KNOX       BOAT
KNOX       HOUSE
SAM        TRAIN
SAM        BOAT
SAM        HOUSE

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```

... this query extracts the one who has visited all of them...

```
SQL> select s.sname
  2  from   salesman s
  3  where s.sid not in  (
  4      select sid from (
  5          select cjs.sid, cjl.lid
  6          from   salesman cjs
  7                 cross join location cjl
  8          minus
  9          select sl.sid, sl.lid
 10          from   sales_loc sl
 11      )
 12  )
 13  /

SNAME  
------ ----
SAM

SQL>
```

Comment: Anyone using this query in sqlserver should change minus to except.

Comment: You should also attach an alias to the second select statement. select ss.sid from (...)

Answer (score 0):

This should work. I've tried it out.

```
select a.sid, a.salesman, count(a.sid) as total from salesman a
inner join sales_loc b on b.sid = a.sid
inner join location c on c.lid = b.lid
group by a.sid, a.salesman
having count(a.sid) = (select count(*) from location)
```

It uses the total number of locations to compare.

Answer (score 0):

salesman(sid,sname)
location(lid,lname)
sales_loc(sid,lid)

select s.sid,s.sname from salesman s,location l, sales_loc sl
where s.sid=sl.sid
and l.lid=sl.lid